# Electrical Circuits Modelling and Formal Proofs

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, electromagnetism

Are there any textbooks or articles that formalizes/models electrical circuits (e.g. using graphs, which is probably the most likely approach to be taken) in a precise manner such that we could rigorously prove properties about circuits, like series and parallel sub-circuit substitutions, delta-wye conversions, Thevenin/Norton's theorems, the fact that every circuit has a unique solution for each voltage/current (given that initial conditions are properly set for circuits whose equations are differential), and so on?

I think I can sketch some of the proofs but it would really help if there were any references written by experts.

Comment: Are you asking specifically about resistive networks?

Comment: Not exclusively resistive networks, but also the ones containing capacitors and inductors.

Comment: Well, Bamberg & Sternberg’s old _A Course In Mathematics For Students of Physics_ devotes a large part of the second volume to resistive networks as a vehicle for introducing cohomology theory. They touch on what changes if you include capacitors and inductors and then switch to capacitive networks as a discrete analog to Maxwell’s equations. I think any competent book on graph theory will also give you some of what you’re looking for.